# How to get the ToolBar like Hangouts

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

I am working on an app and I have something similar to the Hangouts app where there is the sliding tabs under the ToolBar but I wanted to integrate it into the ToolBar instead of existing in the Activity/Fragment layout.

I have tried increasing the height of the ToolBar and setting a custom view, but if I do that, the custom view is in the middle of the ToolBar and not underneath the Title and Menu Overflow Button.

I have tried several things. Latest is:

```
toolBar.setCustomView(customView, layoutParams);
```

Any help would be great.

EDIT: Should have been more clear...

I want the tabs like this to be in the ToolBar not in the Fragment Layout like this, 
https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/res/layout/fragment_sample.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `OnScrollChanged` function in your `ScrollView`. `ActionBar` doesn't let you set the opacity , so set a background drawable on the actionbar and you can change its opacity based on the amount of scroll in the scrollview. I have given an example workflow

The function sets gives the appropriate alpha for the view locationImage based on its position WRT window .

`this.getScrollY()` gives you how much the `scrollView` has scrolled

```
public void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    // Code ...
    locationImage.setAlpha(getAlphaForView(locationImageInitialLocation- this.getScrollY()));
}


private float getAlphaForView(int position) {
    int diff = 0;
    float minAlpha = 0.4f, maxAlpha = 1.f;
    float alpha = minAlpha; // min alpha
    if (position > screenHeight)
        alpha = minAlpha;
    else if (position + locationImageHeight < screenHeight)
        alpha = maxAlpha;
    else {
        diff = screenHeight - position;
        alpha += ((diff * 1f) / locationImageHeight)* (maxAlpha - minAlpha); // 1f and 0.4f are maximum and min
                                            // alpha
        // this will return a number betn 0f and 0.6f
    }
    // System.out.println(alpha+" "+screenHeight +" "+locationImageInitialLocation+" "+position+" "+diff);
    return alpha;
}
```

An example working sample at https://github.com/ramanadv/fadingActionBar , you can have a look at it.

[image]

Comment: I added an image of what I meant

Comment: You need to create a custom Action Bar view of your own and add that in your activity.